# How can I install a self-signed star cert with a self-generated root CA that openssl will verify against?

Tags: certificates, openssl, certificate-revocation, socat

I'm trying to **test** some services and they need to talk to each other over https ( and they can't talk over http).  I want to:

1. create a Root CA that I [can install in my Ubuntu-based docker images](https://askubuntu.com/a/94861/10592)
2. sign a subdomain cert like `*.example.com` such that curl and openssl will validate against it, with the root CA cert manually installed into the Ubuntu system.

In pursuit of 2, I've tried following [this chap's example](https://openthreat.ro/create-your-own-custom-root-ca-with-openssl/), but I'm not sure if it works with star certs.

I cobbled together the sequence of steps into a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

SUBDOMAIN=example.com

openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key -passout pass:pass 4096

openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 2048 -out rootCA.crt \
  -passin pass:pass \
  -subj "/C=US/ST=WA/L=Seattle/O=Foo/OU=bar/CN=*.$SUBDOMAIN"
  
openssl genrsa -out star.$SUBDOMAIN.key 4096

openssl req -new -key star.$SUBDOMAIN.key -out star.$SUBDOMAIN.csr \
  -subj "/C=US/ST=WA/L=Seattle/O=Foo/OU=bar/CN=*.$SUBDOMAIN"
  
cat > $SUBDOMAIN.ext <<EOF
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = *.$SUBDOMAIN

EOF
  
openssl x509 -req -in star.$SUBDOMAIN.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key \
  -CAcreateserial -out star.$SUBDOMAIN.crt -days 3650 -sha256 -passin pass:pass \
  -extfile $SUBDOMAIN.ext
  
openssl x509 -in star.$SUBDOMAIN.crt -text -noout

cat star.$SUBDOMAIN.crt star.$SUBDOMAIN.key > star.$SUBDOMAIN.pem

socat openssl-listen:4433,reuseaddr,fork,forever,cert=star.$SUBDOMAIN.pem,cafile=star.$SUBDOMAIN.crt \
  exec:'/bin/cat' &
  
openssl s_client -CAfile rootCA.crt  --connect localhost:4433

kill %
```

When openssl runs at the end, it fails to validate with a message:

```
[...]
Verification error: unable to verify the first certificate
[...]
```

Is there something glaring about this cert generation flow that would cause openssl to reject it?  I've tried curl and openssl on full verbosity, but this eludes me.

Full log:

```
+ export SUBDOMAIN=example.com
+ SUBDOMAIN=example.com
+ openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key -passout pass:pass 4096
Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus (2 primes)
..........................................................................................................................................++++
.............................++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)
+ openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 2048 -out rootCA.crt -passin pass:pass -subj '/C=US/ST=WA/L=Seattle/O=Foo/OU=bar/CN=*.example.com'
+ openssl genrsa -out star.example.com.key 4096
Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus (2 primes)
..............................................++++
........................................................................++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)
+ openssl req -new -key star.example.com.key -out star.example.com.csr -subj '/C=US/ST=WA/L=Seattle/O=Foo/OU=bar/CN=*.example.com'
+ cat
+ openssl x509 -req -in star.example.com.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out star.example.com.crt -days 3650 -sha256 -passin pass:pass -extfile example.com.ext
Signature ok
subject=C = US, ST = WA, L = Seattle, O = Foo, OU = bar, CN = *.example.com
Getting CA Private Key
+ openssl x509 -in star.example.com.crt -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            71:bb:c2:01:cb:c8:e4:b0:b8:9f:0f:45:0b:52:67:b8:ae:9f:d8:af
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, ST = WA, L = Seattle, O = Foo, OU = bar, CN = *.example.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Aug  4 02:52:01 2021 GMT
            Not After : Aug  2 02:52:01 2031 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = WA, L = Seattle, O = Foo, OU = bar, CN = *.example.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:97:13:94:b2:51:9d:40:2a:09:b3:b0:7a:57:d7:
                    a2:22:d5:91:8b:4f:6a:b0:2d:55:00:95:9e:79:31:
                    75:3e:44:85:6c:59:54:d5:1e:bb:d8:61:e2:f1:4e:
                    e1:7d:83:d7:a0:c2:56:fd:f8:b9:b9:b0:f4:db:69:
                    3b:51:76:63:04:43:04:37:3c:bb:53:33:6b:b2:32:
                    c2:9c:a3:0a:88:d3:be:ac:4d:5c:c8:05:0d:8c:79:
                    82:f4:b7:ac:00:d3:fb:14:a8:e7:84:d3:27:20:1e:
                    a7:79:13:86:b5:94:79:f1:cc:31:ff:d6:d9:2a:99:
                    ac:13:9c:c6:8c:67:17:19:c4:57:95:7d:ad:bd:f8:
                    2a:70:08:67:5f:2f:c7:09:5a:df:bd:a7:75:6a:a7:
                    f9:83:32:ee:24:2b:d5:a2:f5:ac:b5:76:78:32:e5:
                    67:88:2a:5b:e7:ed:c3:17:bb:b8:0f:dc:80:c5:f9:
                    0a:d3:68:51:78:fd:c8:33:b0:db:42:46:0c:e1:4e:
                    93:77:ad:fb:4f:2e:47:98:6b:09:4d:94:40:ba:cd:
                    88:ed:85:ce:3f:2a:85:25:e9:0a:7e:4c:ba:b5:da:
                    d6:b9:6d:75:9a:5d:40:94:fc:c6:d0:77:8c:55:99:
                    ff:fd:d7:71:49:0b:03:75:f0:7a:11:d5:9a:19:57:
                    57:17:12:18:c4:55:c2:c5:44:1e:d5:4b:06:60:39:
                    4f:2b:17:81:63:14:e0:f3:75:2c:fb:b2:78:76:c6:
                    74:e4:7d:7f:25:db:c5:66:0a:64:6a:36:c6:8d:b9:
                    f7:5c:dc:77:a9:2f:4a:94:1a:da:8c:fb:ac:b7:64:
                    e6:d4:6c:d0:e9:9c:64:05:5d:96:81:fa:20:87:2a:
                    56:25:dc:96:ce:90:8c:ba:ef:3b:2e:9a:8b:db:54:
                    84:48:4e:59:d1:e5:31:f8:e6:57:97:b5:3b:fa:d7:
                    de:63:c5:94:c2:2a:07:50:6d:58:5b:87:ed:b3:5e:
                    af:15:14:9e:2e:65:c1:df:2c:4d:35:2b:ce:24:f9:
                    ad:8b:5e:6c:00:6d:ce:28:2a:33:33:bd:8e:1a:64:
                    cd:15:72:85:79:7e:e7:bd:07:74:d7:0c:c6:8b:7d:
                    29:5f:71:d2:f7:82:17:15:00:57:2b:14:1c:f8:cb:
                    c4:25:51:79:62:d2:41:18:44:18:a4:4b:1e:6a:f2:
                    16:33:e5:47:39:73:5c:8b:d8:39:4b:f3:79:b2:12:
                    90:68:98:8f:18:8a:18:e8:5a:e0:c4:c8:88:e6:e4:
                    8f:5a:59:b4:9f:d7:81:ed:d5:e3:23:f9:86:6e:d1:
                    6d:a1:00:d0:f9:44:42:9e:3d:d3:50:97:ee:26:bf:
                    c3:18:35
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:44:EE:13:83:5C:D7:C8:11:78:64:A2:F1:E1:9C:CF:D9:F2:FE:57:7E

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:*.example.com
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         2c:fb:18:13:84:86:c4:f9:87:ab:ae:c6:bf:b9:48:75:d0:83:
         a0:5b:06:01:ca:72:c5:8f:9e:f7:29:6d:eb:d2:6b:9d:2d:ad:
         34:49:27:b8:8e:e6:06:70:52:94:e7:e6:54:67:73:93:dc:43:
         05:28:ad:6d:f8:e1:34:ad:52:e2:bf:36:0d:e9:a6:f1:21:17:
         87:8c:92:15:62:57:60:72:a2:c7:86:b9:b3:7d:8b:be:4b:14:
         32:8e:4d:17:60:21:f2:76:d5:1f:55:89:d6:bb:b6:0e:f7:f9:
         1d:98:cb:01:ee:59:43:a5:99:96:5d:3c:da:23:61:4a:5c:6a:
         64:e2:87:eb:a0:02:e9:6c:1c:f5:32:52:b5:bb:56:c3:a8:10:
         84:6e:b2:df:33:28:11:ec:fd:1f:08:d4:5a:45:ed:a7:ea:4d:
         57:8e:9a:44:a1:b5:65:05:ed:5e:1e:8d:c1:52:fa:be:1d:1e:
         6c:4a:be:5d:a2:fb:9f:19:3e:1e:5c:20:15:ce:0a:95:c3:d6:
         b0:f8:44:71:3b:66:e3:e2:54:f2:f5:08:72:04:5a:90:fb:65:
         47:e2:aa:9f:a7:5c:e1:e4:00:09:cc:e7:e7:a5:4a:58:04:53:
         50:52:6b:92:60:2e:44:59:78:2c:5f:d0:b4:86:fe:e0:44:f1:
         a2:0d:79:55:51:fb:65:81:c5:06:3c:d7:5a:4d:71:39:72:8c:
         ee:df:4b:ed:2e:f8:f7:7a:59:b7:7b:76:93:bd:f5:1d:80:86:
         19:23:5e:b8:d9:2e:e5:67:64:ce:7c:05:5d:c7:40:3f:cf:80:
         50:40:42:38:34:12:ef:f0:e5:31:04:5e:1b:48:15:17:ed:a6:
         76:f0:0d:fb:5e:40:fd:f4:6c:a0:4d:b8:06:37:c1:75:04:e2:
         04:b8:ce:9c:17:cb:3a:ab:20:d9:a5:0b:4f:07:ed:14:71:13:
         52:38:b5:dd:ca:05:e9:6c:27:37:9e:c2:44:40:2b:50:16:df:
         eb:0a:11:6c:33:ec:05:82:6c:bc:24:5f:c1:12:44:19:02:62:
         02:79:8b:1f:f4:7f:77:6b:e4:42:89:cd:19:61:65:e0:79:a3:
         33:48:98:e4:da:76:86:48:42:19:da:a0:6f:e0:d8:34:ab:dc:
         a5:c5:03:c4:a8:7a:7a:96:20:bd:08:b0:07:5e:6b:da:9b:30:
         fa:71:15:27:ee:c8:38:73:33:8b:8e:f4:a4:f5:a4:4a:c6:41:
         9e:96:34:d4:21:1b:88:60:48:22:61:2d:d0:5a:5f:a4:47:50:
         1c:76:81:89:b6:84:dc:05:c0:e1:a4:ca:c7:cf:43:34:ba:ae:
         ce:c4:a4:e3:5d:7c:21:d6
+ cat star.example.com.crt star.example.com.key
+ openssl s_client -CAfile rootCA.crt --connect localhost:4433
+ socat openssl-listen:4433,reuseaddr,fork,forever,cert=star.example.com.pem,cafile=star.example.com.crt exec:/bin/cat
depth=0 C = US, ST = WA, L = Seattle, O = Foo, OU = bar, CN = *.example.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = WA, L = Seattle, O = Foo, OU = bar, CN = *.example.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
139679332975040:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1528:SSL alert number 40
CONNECTED(00000005)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = US, ST = WA, L = Seattle, O = Foo, OU = bar, CN = *.example.com
   i:C = US, ST = WA, L = Seattle, O = Foo, OU = bar, CN = *.example.com
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=C = US, ST = WA, L = Seattle, O = Foo, OU = bar, CN = *.example.com

issuer=C = US, ST = WA, L = Seattle, O = Foo, OU = bar, CN = *.example.com

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:Ed25519:Ed448:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA384:DSA+SHA512
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:Ed25519:Ed448:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA384:DSA+SHA512
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2205 bytes and written 449 bytes
Verification error: unable to verify the first certificate
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 093BFC9F755DDE826FA6D83C9DFFEAD03033DE4ED32247FBEF0A652D1DF8832C464FEBFD7533D08584B05882702FD649
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1628045521
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
+ kill %
```

Comment: Looks like there is only one certificate in your chain. You need to send the whole chain including your root from the server. It is written in a single PEM file with sections

Comment: TLS servers send the end entity (leaf) cert and all the intermediates, but not the root to the client during handshake. Since there is no intermediate here, I think sending just the leaf is correct.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to give both CA and certificate the same subject. This way it looks like a self-signed certificate and might lead to confusion when trying to lookup the issuer CA.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich do you think it should remain on the security stack? It looks for me like script troubleshooting.

Comment: @nethero: I'm not sure. If the problem is caused by using the same subject in cert and issuer explaining such issues is probably on-topic.

Comment: The subject should not pose the issue, but this is so poor I don't know where to start. Use of des3, wildcard CN in the root certificate. Looks like op is barely knowing what he's doing.

Comment: Additionally, it is not a star certificate, it is a wildcard.

Comment: Yup. You're totally right I don't know what I'm doing, which is why I'm asking the experts.  I'm playing copy-pasta and reading people's playbooks to try to get a foothold in this world.  I tried to give a great [S.S.C.C.E.](http://www.sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on feedback from @steffen-ullrich and @nethero in their comments and answers, the hangups that I had were the `-des3` switch to the root CA, the duplicate subjects in root and leaf certs, and getting pass socat issues.

Solution was to nuke `des3` switch, change the duplicate subjects, and instruct socat to ignore verification *in this test environment*.

The following sequence of openssl commands seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
  
export SUBDOMAIN=example.com

openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key -passout pass:pass 4096

openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 2048 -out rootCA.crt \
  -passin pass:pass \
  -subj "/C=US/ST=WA/L=Seattle/O=Mother/OU=Ship/CN=root.ca"
  
openssl genrsa -out star.$SUBDOMAIN.key 4096

openssl req -new -key star.$SUBDOMAIN.key -out star.$SUBDOMAIN.csr \
  -subj "/C=US/ST=WA/L=Seattle/O=Foo/OU=Bar/CN=$SUBDOMAIN"
  
cat > $SUBDOMAIN.ext <<EOF
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = *.$SUBDOMAIN

EOF
  
openssl x509 -req -in star.$SUBDOMAIN.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key \
  -CAcreateserial -out star.$SUBDOMAIN.crt -days 3650 -sha256 -passin pass:pass \
  -extfile $SUBDOMAIN.ext
  
openssl x509 -in star.$SUBDOMAIN.crt -text -noout

cat star.$SUBDOMAIN.crt star.$SUBDOMAIN.key > star.$SUBDOMAIN.pem

echo socat openssl-listen:4433,reuseaddr,fork,forever,cert=star.$SUBDOMAIN.pem,cafile=star.$SUBDOMAIN.crt,verify=0 \
  exec:'/bin/cat' &
 
sleep 1

openssl s_client -debug -CAfile rootCA.crt  -connect localhost:4433

killall socat
```

Installed in test Ubuntu with:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra
sudo cp rootCA.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Answer (score 1):

From socat documentation we can read the following:

> cafile= Specifies the file with the trusted (root) authority
> certificates. The file must be in PEM format and should contain one or
> more certificates. The party that checks the authentication of its
> peer trusts only certificates that are in this file.

I think your certificate may not contain the root CA that is required for this to work.